# Can not connect SMTP Server In node JS Local server using Google account

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I  was not able to connect to SMTP Server In node JS Local server using Google account.
i have tried my local server for sending mail using google but i encountered these errors.
How can i solve this?

Here was my code :

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '*****@gmail.com',
    pass: '****'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
      from: '****@gmail.com',
      to: '******@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
      text: 'That was easy!'
    };  

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });
```

**Error**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'nodemailer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dev5_etech/socket/app.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: Did you install nodemailer using `npm install nodemailer`?

Comment: Yes i was install  npm install nodemailer

Comment: can you post your package.json in the question?

Comment: @Dharman i have fixed tags.

Comment: @jalodarajayesh please add package.json

Comment: @RajanSharma
    Here is my package.json file :

    {
  "name": "socketapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Socket Application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "start": "node app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    ""
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}

Comment: @jalodarajayesh I think nodemailer is not installed properly in your project.Please reinstall it.

Comment: @RajPurohit using this command  `npm install nodemailer`
 i was install nodemailer

Comment: @jalodarajayesh but in your package.json there is no mention about nodemailer

Comment: @RajPurohit 
i was not user `npm install nodemailer --save ` i was not necessary to include dependency in package.json file

Comment: @jalodarajayesh but if nodemailer installed properly then it shows in package.json but in your case, that's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single line command you will install  nodemailer package.

```
npm install --g nodemailer --save
```

Answer (score 1):

@jayesh

first
`npm -g install nodemailer`

then
`npm install  nodemailer --save`

Than after you can see in your `package.json` file is the

```
"name": "appication name",
"description": "...",
"version": "0.0.3",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.17.1",
  "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
  "socket.io": "^2.2.0"
  "nodemailer":"^0.4.0"
}
```

If you try and run as per this command and solve you problem.

Comment: Thank you Etech Dev 

IT was worked i was try as per your guide line and run command